# Are Alexa skills using AWS Lambda still restricted to N Virgina and Ireland?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

From paragraph 4 in [here](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-howto/blob/master/instructions/3-connect-vui-to-code.md), it says:

> Remember, Alexa skills using AWS Lambda can only run in N. Virginia (North America) and Ireland (Europe).

Is this still the current situation?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to deploy them in another region?  Presumably, these are where the Alexa *service* is running and this constraint is there so that it can access the skills with the lowest latency.

Comment: My dyanamoDB is in Oregon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda Functions for Alexa Skills can now be hosted in `US West (Oregon)` as well.

When configuring the Lambda endpoint for your skill, you can provide a `Default endpoint` as well as three other optional `geographical region endpoints` which will be called based on the customer’s location for better latency.

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/develop-skills-in-multiple-languages.html#h2-multiple-endpoints

Your skill configuration will be like below:

[image: skill config]